# Magento, Яндекс.Касса и холдирование

Tags: json, ajax, magento, яндекс-касса

Столкнулся с проблемой при подключении холдирования к модулю Яндекс.Кассы от Mygento(1.3.6) к Magento(1.7.0.2).

Оформляю заказ как пользователь, ввожу данные карточки, совершаю платеж, деньги снимаются и замораживаются в админке Яндекс.Кассы, затем нужно на странице заказа в админке magento "одобрить" платеж или "отменить", но у меня эти кнопки не отображаются. Проблема в том, что не работает условие, которое проверяет установлена ли двухстадийная оплата или нет.

```
<?php if ($this->getOrder()->canInvoice() && $this->isTwoFactor()): ?>
```

А именно

```
$this->isTwoFactor()
```

Если убрать это условие и нажать на появившуюся кнопку "одобрить", то после выполнения аякс запроса появится алерт с надписью "no XML data".

В админке точно правильно указаны все shopID и scid для двух магазинов(без холдирования и для холдирования, также подключены сертификат и приватный ключ).

Также обратил внимание на url кнопки "одобрить" -

```
https://shhmarket.ru/index.php/admin/yandexkassa_confirm/index/orderid/6227/key/ecfff44ea1ce400bdb7df141ad223b05/?isAjax=true
```

Разве в этом урле не должны передаваться параметры confirmPayment метода? orderID, currency, requestDT и amount?

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста!

Всем спасибо и хорошего вечера!